# Loading Data into Neo4j and creating relationships

Tags: neo4j

I've just started playing around with Neo4j and I'm having trouble loading my data in correctly. The problem I have that my data is in the following format:

`Col A  | Col B  | Num Messages|
User 1 | User 8 | 1           |
User 1 | User 2 | 2           |
User 1 | User 5 | 1           |
User 2 | User 7 | 1           |
User 8 | User 1 | 4           |
User 5 | User 2 | 1           |`

What I want to do is create a node for each unique user and then show the relationship based on the rows of the table, taking into account a user can appear in both columns multiple times, but messaging a different user

When I load the data in I was trying to use the following command: However this creates duplicates and I cant find a way to define the relationship

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/data/neo_data_trial.csv" AS line 
CREATE (p:Players {id: line['1']}), (s:Players {id: line['2']})
```

I've looked over the documentation and can't find an easy way to do this. Does anybody have any suggestions or can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want `MERGE` to start:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/data/neo_data_trial.csv" AS line 
MERGE (p:Players {id: line['1']})
MERGE (s:Players {id: line['2']})
```

Once you have that you can create the relationships:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/data/neo_data_trial.csv" AS line 
MERGE (p:Players {id: line['1']})
MERGE (s:Players {id: line['2']})
CREATE (p)-[:PLAYS_WITH]->(s)
```

I just made up the relationship type `PLAYS_WITH`.  You're free to change that, of course.

You can use `MERGE` to create the relationship as well.  It depends on if you want a unique relationship for every row in your file (and it might not even make a difference if you don't ever repeat `p` and `s`)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply, using the MERGE makes sense now, however I get this strange error and can't seem to fond any info on it:    "Cannot merge node using null property value for id"   . I checked my csv file and there are no null values

Comment: I finally solved it with MERGE (p:Players {name: line.id})
MERGE (s:Players {name: line.id})
CREATE (p)-[:PLAYS_WITH]->(s);      Thanks for the help

Comment: Awesome, glad you figured it out!